# Django PIL error with reading file using S3

Tags: django, django-models

Django newbie :)

I'm using **S3 storage** via the package [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This appears to work perfect when I upload/update a new image via the admin.

**models.py** (image field)

```
 image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=path_and_rename("profiles"),
        height_field="image_height",
        width_field="image_width",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=True,
        help_text="Profile Picture",
        verbose_name="Profile Picture"
    )
    image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False, default="100")
    image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False, default="100")
```

I then decided I wanted to resize the image upon upload so try by adding the following code on save override method...

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):


        if not self.id and not self.image:
            return

        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


        image = Image.open(self.image).seek(0)
        (width, height) = image.size
        size = ( 100, 100)
        image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(self.image.path)
```

Here is the problem, this gave the following error....

**cannot identify image file**

I then posted a question on stack yesterday *(which I deleted)* and a user linked to this answer [Django PIL : IOError Cannot identify image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950745/django-pil-ioerror-cannot-identify-image-file) which I sorta understand (because the image has not uploaded it cannot read it yet). **But I'm not sure that that is my issue!** When I get the error **cannot identify image file** I can see the original file has actually been uploaded to S3 *(without the resize of course)*.

**Remembering I'm a newbie** can anyone modify my example save method *(and explain)* with a way to resolve this issue? i.e. a way to rezise a new image to 100x100 on upload?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the storage to read the file if its already written then resize....

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and not self.image:
            return

        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


        import urllib2 as urllib
        from cStringIO import StringIO
        from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

        '''Open original photo which we want to resize using PIL's Image object'''
        img_file = urllib.urlopen(self.image.url)
        im = StringIO(img_file.read())
        resized_image = Image.open(im)




        '''Convert to RGB if necessary'''
        if resized_image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
            resized_image = resized_image.convert('RGB')

        '''We use our PIL Image object to create the resized image, which already
        has a thumbnail() convenicne method that constrains proportions.
        Additionally, we use Image.ANTIALIAS to make the image look better.
        Without antialiasing the image pattern artificats may reulst.'''
        resized_image.thumbnail((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        '''Save the resized image'''
        temp_handle = StringIO()
        resized_image.save(temp_handle, 'jpeg')
        temp_handle.seek(0)

        ''' Save to the image field'''
        suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(self.image.name)[-1].split('.')[0],
                                 temp_handle.read(), content_type='image/jpeg')
        self.image.save('%s.jpg' % suf.name, suf, save=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect

```
image.save(self.image.path)
```

to work. Shouldn't you open it with

```
image = Image.open(self.image.path).seek(0)
```

?