# Django creating image Thumbnails "cannot identify image file"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am trying to resize and save thumbnails of an image in multiple different sizes every time a user updates their profile picture.

```
full_profile_picture = self.profile_picture

logger.debug("Profile Picture 1: " + str(self.profile_picture))
thumbnail_size = (288,288)
image_288 = Image.open(full_profile_picture)
if image_288.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'): image_288 = image_288.convert('RGB')
image_288.thumbnail(thumbnail_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
temp_handle = StringIO()
image_288.save(temp_handle, 'png')
temp_handle.seek(0)
file_name = str(uuid4()) + ".png"
suf = SimpleUploadedFile(file_name, temp_handle.read(), content_type='image/png')
self.profile_picture_288.save(file_name, suf, save=False)



logger.debug("Profile Picture 2: " + str(self.profile_picture))  
thumbnail_size = (216,216)
image_216 = Image.open(full_profile_picture)
if image_216.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'): image_216 = image_216.convert('RGB')
image_216.thumbnail(thumbnail_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
temp_handle1 = StringIO()
image_216.save(temp_handle1, 'png')
temp_handle1.seek(0)
file_name = str(uuid4()) + ".png"
suf = SimpleUploadedFile(file_name, temp_handle1.read(), content_type='image/png')
self.profile_picture_216.save(file_name, suf, save=False)
```

For some reason, the 1st thumbnail will save find, however the second gives me this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST

Django Version: 1.6
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'paintstore',
 'main',

Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/x/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mark/projects/django2/userprofile/views.py" in edit_profile
  25.             update_profile_form.save()
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/x/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  437.                              construct=False)
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/x/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  94.         instance.save()
File "/home/mark/projects/django2/core/models.py" in save
  752.                     image_216 = Image.open(full_profile_picture)
File "/usr/local/virtualenvs/x/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in open
  2006.     raise IOError("cannot identify image file")

Exception Type: IOError at /profile/update/
Exception Value: cannot identify image file
```

Comment: Firstly, consider using try-except blocks when opening and working with file objects. As for your problem, I suspect that you are incorrectly saving (perhaps overwriting) your original image when you create the first thumbnail. Most likely, your original image file header is getting corrupted before you open the file the second time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950745/django-pil-ioerror-cannot-identify-image-file?rq=1